# I can choose one person from my list in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to choose one person from my list in JS but whenever I check the out it give me all  of them
I think I have problem in array but I couldn't solve my problem.

Here is my code.

```js
const names = ["Mary", "Anna", "Angel", "Nish", "Jack", "Pam"];
console.log(names); // shows all

function whosPaying(names) {
  var numberOfPeople = names.length;
  var randomPersonPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfPeople);
  var randomPerson = names[randomPersonPosition];
  return randomPerson + " is going to pay."
}

console.log(whosPaying(names))
```

Comment: what does `console.log(whosPaying(names))` give and what do you think it should give?

Comment: The code you've posted _does_ pick one person from the array.

Comment: thank you @DavidJonesI didn't know How could I write
it was just giving me all ["Mary", "Anna" ,"Angel", "Nish" , "Jack", "Pam"]

Comment: @jonrsharpe my problem was about how to write console for output 
thanks.

Comment: I made a snippet. The code works if called the way it was supposed to

Comment: To show all: `console.log(names)`

Answer (score -2):

You've got the answer in your original post... you just need to write the RESULT OF THE FUNCTION to the console, just like you did with the `const random`... i.e.

```
names = ["Mary", "Anna" ,"Angel", "Nish" , "Jack", "Pam"];


function whosPaying(names) {
  var numberOfPeople = names.length;
  var randomPersonPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfPeople );
  var randomPerson = names [randomPersonPosition];
  return randomPerson + " is going to pay."
}
console.log(whosPaying(names));
```

**THIS IS THE PART YOUR MISSING:**
`console.log(whosPaying(names));`

Answer (score -3):

```
names = ["Mary", "Anna" ,"Angel", "Nish" , "Jack", "Pam"];
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);

console.log(random, names[random]);
```

here is the souloution but I need to know if there is any way to solve it without const ?

Comment: You've got the answer in your original post... you just need to write the RESULT OF THE FUNCTION to the console, just like you did with the `const random`... i.e.  just use `console.log(whosPaying);` after your function declaration.

Comment: you're very welcome! Stack overflow will be a great resource in learning JS... good luck!  BTW, above I meant `console.log(whosPaying(names))`